# Need help in SQL Query 5

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have data by each employee for each day.  Below is the sample data.

```
WITH RawData as 
(  
SELECT '10001' AS EmpNo,'2015-01-01' as AttendanceDate,'FS' AS ShiftCode UNION 
SELECT '10001','2015-01-02','WO' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-03','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-04','FS' UNION 
SELECT '10001','2015-01-05','FS' UNION 
SELECT '10001','2015-01-06','FS' UNION 
SELECT '10001','2015-01-07','FS' UNION 
SELECT '10001','2015-01-08','FS' UNION 
SELECT '10001','2015-01-09','WO' UNION 
SELECT '10001','2015-01-10','FS' UNION 
SELECT '10001','2015-01-11','FS' UNION 
SELECT '10001','2015-01-12','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-13','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-14','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-15','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-16','WO' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-17','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-18','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-19','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-20','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-21','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-22','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-23','WO' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-24','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-25','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-26','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-27','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-28','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-29','FS' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-30','WO' UNION
SELECT '10001','2015-01-31','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-01','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-02','WO' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-03','WO' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-04','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-05','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-06','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-07','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-08','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-09','WO' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-10','WO' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-11','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-12','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-13','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-14','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-15','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-16','WO' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-17','WO' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-18','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-19','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-20','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-21','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-22','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-23','WO' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-24','WO' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-25','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-26','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-27','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-28','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-29','FS' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-30','WO' UNION
SELECT '10002','2015-01-31','WO')
SELECT * FROM RawData Order By EmpNo,AttendanceDate
```

How to write SQL Query to get following output based on this sample data ? The workweek of each employee starts on a Day after weekly off and it can be any day (mon, tue etc). The shift code denotes WO: weekly off, FS: First Shift, SS: Second Shift.

```
EmpNo  WeekFrom     WeekTo     
10001  2015-01-01   2015-01-02
10001  2015-01-03   2015-01-09
10001  2015-01-10   2015-01-16
10001  2015-01-17   2015-01-23
10001  2015-01-24   2015-01-30
10001  2015-01-31   2015-01-31
10002  2015-01-01   2015-01-03
10002  2015-01-04   2015-01-10
10002  2015-01-11   2015-01-17
10002  2015-01-18   2015-01-24
10002  2015-01-25   2015-01-31
```

Got a solution. But its taking quite a long time on live table with 1 Million rows. Have I done something wrong in a query ? Or there is a better way of doing this.

```
WITH RawData as 
(  
-- Insert above data here.
)
,ProcessData AS (
SELECT EmpNo,AttendanceDate,ShiftCode,RowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY EmpNo, AttendanceDate
        ), WeekNo = 1 FROM RawData 
        )
,FinalData
AS (
    SELECT EmpNo, AttendanceDate, ShiftCode, RowID, WeekNo = 1
    FROM ProcessData DA
    WHERE RowID = 1 
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT DA.EmpNo, DA.AttendanceDate, DA.ShiftCode, DA.RowID, 
    WeekNo = (CASE WHEN FinalData.EmpNo != DA.EmpNo THEN 1 ELSE FinalData.WeekNo + (CASE WHEN (FinalData.ShiftCode = 'WO' AND DA.ShiftCode != 'WO') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END)
    FROM FinalData
    INNER JOIN ProcessData  DA ON DA.RowID = FinalData.RowID + 1
    )
SELECT EmpNo, MIN(AttendanceDate) AS StartDate, MAX(AttendanceDate) AS EndDate, WeekNo
FROM FinalData
GROUP BY EmpNo, WeekNo
ORDER BY EmpNo, WeekNo
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Never asked question before hence was not aware of rules. Question edited and posted my solution. Will take care next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this worked. 5 seconds on 230,000 records. I will go ahead with my solution. Thanks for your time. Hope this solution helps someone.

```
-- Step 1 : Save it to temp table
SELECT EmpNo,AttendanceDate,ShiftCode,RowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY EmpNo, AttendanceDate
        ), WeekNo = 1 into #RawData FROM -- My table

-- Step 2 : Use temp table
;WITH FinalData
AS (
    SELECT EmpNo, AttendanceDate, ShiftCode, RowID, WeekNo = 1
    FROM #RawData DA
    WHERE RowID = 1 
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT DA.EmpNo, DA.AttendanceDate, DA.ShiftCode, DA.RowID, 
    WeekNo = (CASE WHEN FinalData.EmpNo != DA.EmpNo THEN 1 ELSE FinalData.WeekNo + (CASE WHEN (FinalData.ShiftCode = 'WO' AND DA.ShiftCode != 'WO') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END)
    FROM FinalData
    INNER JOIN #RawData  DA ON DA.RowID = FinalData.RowID + 1
    )
SELECT EmpNo, MIN(AttendanceDate) AS StartDate, MAX(AttendanceDate) AS EndDate, WeekNo
FROM FinalData
GROUP BY EmpNo, WeekNo
ORDER BY EmpNo, WeekNo  
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It says I can accept only after 2 days. Will try after 2 days.

Comment: I still don't know why saving in temp table improves performance to such an extent.

Comment: I would assume it's all the sorting because of order by + row number that takes a lot of time, but looking into query plan & statistics io output should explain what's happening

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35418/1/0)

```
;WITH RawData AS (  
 -- Your insert statements here
),
Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpNo, grp ORDER BY AttendanceDate DESC)
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
            grp = DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpNo ORDER BY AttendanceDate), AttendanceDate)
        FROM RawData
        WHERE ShiftCode = 'WO'
    )t  
),
CteWeekOff AS(
    SELECT  EmpNo, AttendanceDate, ShiftCode FROM cte WHERE RN = 1
),
CteFinal AS(
    SELECT
        EmpNo,
        WeekFrom = MIN(AttendanceDate),
        Weekto = MAX(AttendanceDate)
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
            grp = DATEADD(DAY, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpNo ORDER BY AttendanceDate), AttendanceDate)
        FROM RawData
        WHERE ShiftCode <> 'WO'
    )t
    GROUP BY EmpNo, grp
)

SELECT
    EmpNo,
    WeekFrom = x.WeekFrom,
    WeekTo = w.AttendanceDate
FROM CteWeekOff w
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 WeekFrom
    FROM CteFinal r
    WHERE
        r.EmpNo = w.EmpNo
        AND r.WeekFrom <= w.AttendanceDate      
    ORDER BY r.WeekFrom DESC
)x(WeekFrom)

UNION ALL

SELECT
    EmpNo, 
    WeekFrom = x.WeekFrom,
    WeekTo = t.AttendanceDate
FROM (
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpNo ORDER BY AttendanceDate DESC)
    FROM RawData
)t
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 AttendanceDate
    FROM CteFinal r
    WHERE
        r.EmpNo = t.EmpNo
        AND r.WeekFrom < t.AttendanceDate       
    ORDER BY r.WeekFrom DESC
)x(WeekFrom)
WHERE 
    RN = 1
    AND ShiftCode <> 'WO'
ORDER BY EmpNo, WeekFrom
```

Comment: Missing 1 day in 1st week for Employee 10001

Missing 2 Days in 1st week and then 1 day in every week.

Comment: Last row for employee 10001, Weekto is 2015-02-01 that is not in table

Comment: Yes It is ;-). We cannot use hard-coded shiftcode other than WO in a query because it could be any. e.g. FS for First Shift, SS for second shift, NS for night shift etc.

Comment: Shall we use ShiftCode <> 'WO' ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Worked on a smaller recordset. However, on 230,000 records, after 4 minutes, I stopped the execution. My query also didn't execute in 4 minutes.

Comment: That's what I thought.